# Поменять логин на имя Chat App

Tags: java, android-studio, listview, chat, firebase-android

Я создал приложение-мессенджер на Firebase. По принципу одного общего чата. Вместо имени у меня находится логин, а я хочу сделать наоборот - вместо логина имя.

Пример - вместо логина *qwerty1234@gmail.com* я хочу что-бы показывалось имя *Qwerty Boy*.

Как это осуществить?

Вот мой код **MainActivity**:

```
 private void displaychatmessage()
{
    ListView listofmessage = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(this, ChatMessage.class, 
    R.layout.list_item, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
            TextView messagetext, messageuser, messagetime;
            messagetext = (BubbleTextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            messageuser = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
            messagetime = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);


            messagetext.setText(model.getMessageText());
            messageuser.setText(model.getMessageUser());
            messagetime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy  (HH, mm,ss)", model.getMessageTime()));

        }
    };
    listofmessage.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

**ChatAppMessage.class**:

```
package com.gulov.alfa;

import java.util.Date;


public class ChatMessage  {
private String messageText;
private String messageUser;
private String messageUserId;
private long messageTime;

public ChatMessage(String messageText, String messageUser) {
    this.messageText = messageText;
    this.messageUser = messageUser;
    messageTime = new Date().getTime();
}

public ChatMessage(){

}

public String getMessageUserId() {
    return messageUserId;
}

public void setMessageUserId(String messageUserId) {
    this.messageUserId = messageUserId;
}

public String getMessageText() {
    return messageText;
}

public void setMessageText(String messageText) {
    this.messageText = messageText;
}

public String getMessageUser() {
    return messageUser;
}

public void setMessageUser(String messageUser) {
    this.messageUser = messageUser;
}

public long getMessageTime() {
    return messageTime;
}

public void setMessageTime(long messageTime) {
    this.messageTime = messageTime;
}
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы хотите что-бы он вводил имя в вашем приложении или показывал имя из G+?

Comment: я хочу вставить вместо логина имя из g+